# Zend Studio - Could not upload resource (problem occurred)

Tags: php, zend-framework, upload, upgrade, zend-studio

I was working in a zend studio project when my computer shut down because of electricity.
Now, whenever I want to do a change in my project and save it, the Zend Studio alerts me the following problem:

[image]

I already tried to uninstall and install the Zend Studio, but the problem continues.

Comment: Not a programming question so not appropriate for Stackoverflow.  However, a quick search yielded [this](https://support.zend.com/hc/en-us/articles/203838506-Resetting-the-Workspace-and-Migrating-Projects-in-Zend-Studio-for-Eclipse).

Answer (score 0):

Had the similar problem.

Just uncheck option Project->Build Automatically from main menu.